# How to get thumbnail from openload.io videos from the video id like youtube

Tags: video, youtube, dailymotion-api, video-thumbnails

For **youtube** we use

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/video-id
```

Where video-id is code of that of video from url

For **Dailymotion** we use

```
http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/video-id
```

What will the thumbnail for openload.io video?

Comment: Anyone here to help me :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use api https://openload.co/api#download-info

```
https://api.openload.co/1/file/getsplash?login={login}&key={key}&file={file}
```